# Extracting the index of an Xcode array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

The following line works fine in the `NSLog`:

```
NSLog(@"Selected Number: %@. Index of selected number: %i", [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row], row);
```

but I would like to make the index assigned to an integer variable:

```
int num = ([arrayNo objectAtIndex:row], row);
```

the line above produces an error. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

An NSArray or NSMutableArray manages objects and can't handle an integer directly. The call to [arrayNo objectAtIndex:row] returns an object. To get the value as an integer you can try:

```
int num = [[arrayNo objectAtIndex:row] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, fetching the object doesn't do anything. You're just throwing it away. What you want to do is:

```
int num = row;
```

If you want to only assign the index for a specific value to num, you can do something like this (assuming array contains only NSNumbers):

```
int num;
for(NSNumber *n in array) {
    if ([n integerValue] == 5) {
        num = [array indexOfObject:n];
        break;
    }
}
```